# user_friends - The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have a Live app using the facebook login javascript sdk/api v3.2 with permissions public_profile. My next version I’d like to add permission user_friends. You need to pass App Review for user_friends.  I created a Test App and Test User with permissions user_friends. When I start to dev with my new test user I get the following error when logging in:  User is not allowed to see the application.: The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration.

[image: browser window login]

Any suggestions on what I should check in my Settings or Roles under my Dashboard on developers.facebook.com?

The code works fine until I added user_friends to the fields property:

```
// assume fb is reference to api returned from 
// https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js

fb.api('/me', { 
    locale: 'en_US', 
    fields: 'first_name,last_name,picture.type(large),user_friends'
}, response => {
    if (onLogin) {
        onLogin(response);
    }
    dispatch(facebookApiMe(response));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

User error :(

1. I was using the wrong appId (using prod appId instead of Test App appId)
2. I need to specify scope as the 2nd arg to the login method from the sdk

```
fb.login(response => {
    dispatch(facebookLogin(response, fb, onLogin));
}, {
    scope: 'user_friends'
});
```